# Two most recurring words in a string without using Collection

Tags: java

I want to find the two words which are recurring the most times in a string, without using Collection.

For example, for the input string:

> to know is to know that they know what we know

The two words recurring the most are: "know" (4 times) and "to" (2 times).

I don't want to use Map here.

I started off by taking a string and splitting it, but I'm lost as how to proceed.
Below gives a pretty weird answer.

```
String s1 = "to know is to know that they know what we know";   
String[] words = s1.split("\\s");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
        if (words[j].contains(words[i])) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(words[i]+" --->" + count);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you attempt to write it yourself, and if you run into _specific_ issues that fit the scope of an SO question, post them here. Please read [ask].

Comment: is it allowed to use a HashMap ?

Comment: I changed it.  pretty new to java

Answer (score -1):

*You are almost there.*

Start `count` at 1 in order to include the current word.

At the end of the second for-loop i.e. the part where you print something, you have to take that word which you just counted and compare it to the current max. If it's bigger, replace the current max with the new count and store the new string which you found.

```
if (count > cMax) {
    cMax = count;
    sMax = words[i];
}
```

In the above, `cMax` is the max count you found for a word so far, this value should be initialized with `0`. `sMax` is the word that has the count stored in `cMax` and it should be initialized with `""` (empty string)

In the end you can now do:

```
System.out.printf("%s ---> %d\n", sMax, cMax);
```

Comment: and second loop should start from zero too `int j = 0;` otherwise it will skip a word, and counts `the actual count -1`.

Comment: @Yazan it doesn't need to start at zero, but the `count` should be set to one not zero

Comment: it's too hard for me to think now lol, but it could work, assuming each word will be exist (at least) once.

Comment: @Yazan, If the word is found, it exists at least once. There is no assumption, which is why `count` should start at 1

Comment: yup, the correct word should be `considering` not assuming, sorry english is not my 1st language